# If my logistic regression model is performing well, does it matter if my features don't pass the Box Tidwell Test?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, logistic-regression

I've built a logistic regression model for binary classification with a high F1 score, but when I run Box-Tidwell tests on continuous independent features/predictive variables, I find non-linearities in the relationship between those features and the logit of the outcome variable. Should I be concerned? I know that linearity between continuous independent variables and the logit of the dependent variable is a fundamental assumption of logistic regression, so I'm inclined to think I should invest time in performing transformations on my features to remove nonlinearities. I'm just confused by the high performance of my model. Would love any guidance on if I should move forward with my model, or spend time revising my features!